# Ionic 2: HTTP requests "pool" and a callback

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic2

I have an algorithm that makes a cache into a SQLite database. I call every endpoint of my API and I save it in my local database. I need to know when all of it is finished.. In angular 1 we have a Promise Queue that invokes a callback when request pool finishes. In ionic 2 / angular 2 how can I achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `rxjs` for that, example (in Typescript):

```
const apiCalls = [
    http.post(apiUrl1, arguments1, ...),
    http.post(apiUrl2, arguments2, ...),
    http.post(apiUrl3, arguments3, ...),
    ...
];

Observable.merge(...apiCalls).subscribe(undefined,undefined,() => myOnComplete());
```

The call to `merge` will cause all requests to run concurrently (when `subscribe` is called). `subscribe` accepts 3 callback functions, onNext (called for each emitted item), onError (called when an error occurs), and onComplete which is called when the observable terminated successfully.

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html